# How do you have an option in a dropdown as the default in Contact Form 7

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I have a date of birth form group, made up of three dropdowns, Month, Day, and Year.

I want the default value in the Year dropdown to be 1960, which I could achieve using the first_as_label command, but I want it to use the 1960 which is surrounded by its corresponding years, rather than sitting at the top, followed by 2000, 1999 etc. See below:

[image]

Is there anyway I can achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

I achieved this using a simple line of jquery:

```
 $('.menu-year select option[value="1960"]').attr("selected",true);
```